# 403 error while testing view in DRF with pytest. JWT auth

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, jwt, pytest, http-status-code-403

There is my view:

```
class ChatView(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               SwaggerTag):
    queryset = Chat.objects.all()
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        with_users = Prefetch('users', queryset=User.objects.exclude(id=self.request.user.id))
        return self.request.user.chat_set.prefetch_related(with_users).all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ChatListSerializer
        elif self.action == 'with_user':
            return ChatSerializer
        elif self.action == 'previous_messages':
            return MessageSerializer
        elif self.action == 'upload_image':
            return ImageUploadSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def with_user(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('user'))
        relation = get_chat_relation(request.user, user)
        with_users = Prefetch('users', queryset=User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id))
        chat, created = Chat.objects.prefetch_related(with_users).get_or_create(relation=relation)
        if created:
            chat.users.set([user, request.user])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(chat)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def previous_messages(self, request, pk):
        instance: Chat = self.get_object()
        qs = instance.message_set.select_related(
            'user_from',
            'advert'
        )
        page = self.paginate_queryset(qs)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def upload_image(self, request):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer = serializer_class(data=request.data, context=self.get_serializer_context())
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

3 custom actions + list.

my urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.urls import include, path
from apps.chat import views

chat_router = DefaultRouter()
chat_router.register('v1/chats', views.ChatView, basename='chats')
```

serializers.py:

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    with_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = (
            'id', 'with_users'
        )

    @swagger_serializer_method(UserShortSerializer(many=True))
    def get_with_users(self, val):
        users = []
        user = self.context['request'].user
        for u in val.users.all():
            if u.id != user.id:
                users.append(u)
        return UserShortSerializer(users, many=True, context=self.context).data


class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_from = UserShortSerializer()
    advert = AdvertShortSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'id', 'user_from', 'image', 'content', 'advert', 'created_at'
        )


class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.ImageField(required=True)

    def save_image(self, file: InMemoryUploadedFile):
        name = f'{generate_string(6)}.png'
        path = f'chat/img/{name}'
        with open(f'{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/{path}', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(file.read())
        return path

    def create(self, validated_data):
        file: InMemoryUploadedFile = validated_data['file']
        instance = {
            'file': self.save_image(file)
        }
        return instance
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance


class WebsocketMessageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    content = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    image = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    advert = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    def validate_advert(self, val):
        if not val:
            return None
        try:
            return Advert.objects.get(id=val)
        except Exception:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Невалидный UUID объявления')


class ChatListSerializer(ChatSerializer):
    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)
        self.fields['last_message'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @swagger_serializer_method(MessageSerializer())
    def get_last_message(self, instance):
        m = instance.message_set.first()
        if m:
            serializer = MessageSerializer(m, context=self.context)
            return serializer.data
        return None
```

also i use jwt for users.

```
The problem is with my test for list-action:
@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient()

@pytest.fixture
def user1():
    return mixer.blend(User)


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_chatview(user1, api_client):
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=user1)
    response = api_client.get(reverse('chats-list'), format='json')
    print(response.content)
    assert response.status_code in (200, 201)
```

error:

pytest apps/chat/tests.py
=============================================================== test session starts ===============================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0
django: settings: Alrent.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aitrix-alrent-ccfa942dfddd, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-12.0.1, cov-4.0.0, django-4.5.2, mock-3.10.0
collected 7 items

apps\chat\tests.py .....F.                                                                                                                   [100%]

==================================================================== FAILURES =====================================================================
__________________________________________________________________ test_chatview __________________________________________________________________

user1 = <User: ncompton@example.org>, api_client = <rest_framework.test.APIClient object at 0x0000025FEBFBA610>

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_chatview(user1, api_client):
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=user1)
    response = api_client.get(reverse('chats-list'), format='json')
    print(response.content)
```

> ```
>   assert response.status_code in (200, 201)
> ```

E       assert 403 in (200, 201)
E        +  where 403 = <Response status_code=403, "application/json">.status_code

apps\chat\tests.py:101: AssertionError
-------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------------------
b'{"detail":"\xd0\xa3 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2 \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f."}'
-------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ---------------------------------------------------------------
Forbidden: /api/v1/chats/
---------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call ----------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING  django.request:log.py:241 Forbidden: /api/v1/chats/
================================================================ warnings summary =================================================================
....\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\coreapi\codecs\download.py:5
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\coreapi\codecs\download.py:5: DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13
import cgi

....\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\compat.py:82
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\compat.py:82: DeprecationWarning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.
for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points().get(namespace, [])

....\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\utils.py:6
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\alrent-TmlPO8pf-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\utils.py:6: RemovedInDjango50Warning: The django.utils.timezone.utc alias is deprecated. Please update your code to use datetime.timezone.utc instead.
from django.utils.timezone import is_naive, make_aware, utc

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
============================================================= short test summary info =============================================================
FAILED apps/chat/tests.py::test_chatview - assert 403 in (200, 201)

In my previous project force_authenticate worked with jwt nicely, but now something goes wrong. Btw, Default permission class is

```
class NotBlocked(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and
                    request.user.is_authenticated and
                    request.user.is_active and
                    not request.user.is_blocked)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better to use APITestCase

```
class TestChatView(APITestCase):
fixtures = ["test_user.json"] # your user model

@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    cls.user = User.objects.first()
    cls.url = reverse("chats-list")

@mock.patch("your_mocked_view_or_task")
def test(self):
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
    resp = self.client.post(self.url)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```